# Swift Cocoa: Change NSScrollView frame size with animation

Tags: swift, cocoa

The result I want to achieve is this:
Kext Wizard :

[image]

I can change the frame size but without any animation. Here is my simple code so far (didn't care too much about size but focus on animation):

```
@IBAction func disclosureButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if disclosureButton.state == .on {
        Swift.print("On")
        kextScroll.setFrameOrigin(kextScroll.frame.origin)
        kextScroll.setFrameSize(NSSize(width: 417, height: 316))
        //let rectBig = NSRect(origin: kextScroll.frame.origin, size: NSSize(width: 417, height: 316))
        //kextScroll.window?.setFrame(rectBig, display: true, animate: true)
    } else if disclosureButton.state == .off {
        Swift.print("Off")
        kextScroll.setFrameOrigin(kextScroll.frame.origin)
        kextScroll.setFrameSize(NSSize(width: 417, height: 200))
    }

}
```

Moreover if someone can give hint on how to show hidden menu as the frame size shrinks would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Use `NSAnimationContext`.

Comment: ok I think I got it animate properly now. Thank you very much! Now the next question is how to bring the hidden menu up. Any thought?

Comment: You can fiddle with the view(menu)'s bottom constraint to get it to show/hide accordingly on button tap. Make sure you set the bottom constraint within an animate block(UIView.animate or AnimationContext) to show/hide too

Comment: I'm think about that as well. But how to make the hidden item shows up from certain boundary (not from window bottom)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem solved by adding NSView to be set as boundary. Here is full code and Xcode picture

```
@IBAction func disclosureButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let dHeight = 70
    let smallOrigin = NSPoint(x: 20, y: 116)
    let bigOrigin = NSPoint(x: 20, y: 116-dHeight)
    let hideOrigin = NSPoint(x:0, y:25-dHeight)
    let showOrigin = NSPoint(x:0, y:25)
    if disclosureButton.state == .on {
        //hide
        NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()
        NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 0.2
        kextScroll.animator().setFrameOrigin(bigOrigin)
        kextScroll.animator().setFrameSize(NSSize(width: 417, height: 249+dHeight))
        pathText.animator().setFrameOrigin(hideOrigin)
        reloadButton.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 269, y:51-dHeight))
        unloadButton.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 347, y:51-dHeight))
        exportButton.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 269, y:-1-dHeight))
        revealButton.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 347, y:-1-dHeight))
        kextLabel.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 0, y:52-dHeight))
        NSAnimationContext.endGrouping()
    } else if disclosureButton.state == .off {
        //show
        NSAnimationContext.beginGrouping()
        NSAnimationContext.current.duration = 0.2
        kextScroll.animator().setFrameOrigin(smallOrigin)
        kextScroll.animator().setFrameSize(NSSize(width: 417, height: 249))
        pathText.animator().setFrameOrigin(showOrigin)
        reloadButton.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 269, y:51))
        unloadButton.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 347, y:51))
        exportButton.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 269, y:-1))
        revealButton.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 347, y:-1))
        kextLabel.animator().setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 0, y:52))
        NSAnimationContext.endGrouping()
    }
}
```

So above code makes sure that all elements moves at same pace, just the question gif looks like. All hidden elements should be in a small NSView to show up properly.

[image: Xcode]
So the element will be invisible if it is outside of the NSView. When the element moves into NSView range, it will not block other elements in the ViewController. Problem solved!